# Wave equation, Closed string and string shooter

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, lagrangian-formalism, string, continuum-mechanics

I have some question about wave equation in "pathological" condition.

1. what is the solution on the wave equation if the string in closed? (ex. a closed string in rotation around his center)

   I guess that it's like the standard wave equation ($\partial _x^2-\partial_t^2)f=0 $ but in this case $x$ is just a parameterization of the string. It's right to say that the correct solution is this equation with the condition $f(0,t)=f(L,t)$ where $x$ is the parametrization of the string?
2. The string shooter. I'm referring to the video ["String shooter-String launcher- physics of toys //// Homemade Science with Bruce Yeany"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rffAjZPmkuU). I have two question about it:

   - I: How can i find the steady shape of the string?

     In the case of a normal sting fixed to the wall in a gravitational field i can write the potential energy of the string in form of functional, minimize it and find the equation of the catenary.

     In the case of the string shooter how can include that kind of "rotation" in the potential energy?
   - II: Suppose that the steady position of the string is known. I want to study the propagation of a wave in the string. How can I derive a PDE that describe the propagation of a wave in a string in this situation?

Comment: Consider to only ask 1 subquestion per post.